# read.csv - to separate information stored in .csv based on the presence or absence of a duplicate value

Tags: r, csv

First of all - apologies, I'm new to all of this, so I may write things in a confusing way.

I have multiple .csv files that I need to read, and to save a lot of time I am looking to find an automated way of doing this. 
I am looking to read different rows of the .csv and store the information as two separate files, based on the information stored in the last column.

My data is specifically areas, and slices of a 3D image, which I will use to compile volumes. If two rows have the same "slice" then I need to separate them, as the area found in row 1 corresponds to a different structure to the one with an area in row 2, on the same slice.

Eg:

Row,area,slice

**1,50,180**

2,52,180

**3,49,181**

4,53,181

5,65,182

6,60,183

So slice structure 1 has an area at slice 180 (area = 50) and 181 (area = 49), whereas structure 2 has an area at each slice from 180 to 183.
I want to be able to store all the bold data in one .csv, and all the other data in another .csv

There may be .csv files with more or less overlapping slice values, adding complexity to this.
Thank you for the help, please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `duplicated`:

```r
dat <- read.csv(text="
Row,area,slice
1,50,180
2,52,180
3,49,181
4,53,181
5,65,182
6,60,183")

dat[duplicated(dat$slice),]
#   Row area slice
# 2   2   52   180
# 4   4   53   181

dat[!duplicated(dat$slice),]
#   Row area slice
# 1   1   50   180
# 3   3   49   181
# 5   5   65   182
# 6   6   60   183
```

(Whether you write each of these last two frames to files or store them for later use is up to you.)

---

`duplicated` normally returns `TRUE` for the second and subsequent incidents of the field(s). Your logic of 2,4,5,6 is more along the lines of "last of the dupes or "no dupes", which is a little different.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(slice) %>%
  slice(-n()) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#     Row  area slice
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1    50   180
# 2     3    49   181
dat %>%
  group_by(slice) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#     Row  area slice
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     2    52   180
# 2     4    53   181
# 3     5    65   182
# 4     6    60   183
```

Similarly, with `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[, .SD[.N,], by = .(slice)]
#    slice Row area
# 1:   180   2   52
# 2:   181   4   53
# 3:   182   5   65
# 4:   183   6   60
as.data.table(dat)[, .SD[-.N,], by = .(slice)]
#    slice Row area
# 1:   180   1   50
# 2:   181   3   49
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Is there a simple way for rows 2,4,5,6 to be group, as with rows 1,3?

Comment: See my edit. It's a little non-standard (per `duplicated`), so I think an alternative might be necessary.